# How to avoid unicode issue when read data from excel

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas dataframe to read data from an excel file. The text becomes this:

```
u"\u200bDuring the QA, bla bla bla,\xa0Head of bla bla\xa0for NZ,\xa0was labelled bla bal. With further investigation, bla bla bla bla bla bla."
```

I tried to replace all of these 'u200b', '\xa0', etc. but still a "\' " cannot be replaced, do not know why?

```
def replaceMultiplePattern(row):             
    for r in ((u'\n', u''), (u'\xa0', u' '), (u'\u2019', "'"), (u'\u2013', '-'), (u'\u200b', ''), (u"\' ", u"'")):
        row = row.replace(*r)
    return row
```

Also, is there anyway can avoid all these unicode conversions when reading data from excel file?

Thank you

Comment: Add a copy of the top 5 rows of the raw data, prior to importing it.  Do not paste in an image though.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding encoding works when importing the file.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.csv' encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: You cant use "pd.read_excel" to read a csv, moreover, "pd.read_excel" does not have encoding. I think you wanted to say pd.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicodedata module after loading your excel in python. 
You can also probably play with the encoding of the excel file when saving it.

```py
text= u"\u200bDuring the QA, bla bla bla,\xa0Head of bla bla\xa0for NZ,\xa0was labelled bla bal. With further investigation, bla bla bla bla bla bla."
from unicodedata import normalize 
t=normalize('NFD',text)
print(t)
```

You might want to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) as they quote

> Even if two unicode strings are normalized and look the same to a human reader, if one has combining characters and the other doesn’t, they may not compare equal.